# How to make AWS S3 upload a reusable function and use the callback from AWS in any file of my choosing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Consider the following S3 Upload code :

```
const Category = require('../models/category');
const Link = require('../models/link');
const slugify = require('slugify');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// s3
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

// Using BASE 64

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const {image, name, content} = req.body;
   const base64Data = new Buffer.from(
    image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''),
    'base64'
  );
  const type = image.split(';')[0].split('/')[1]; // get the png from "data:image/png;base64,"

  // upload image to s3 (The params will be passed to the refactored code)
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'categories-react',
    Key: `category/${uuidv4()}.${type}`,
    Body: base64Data,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: `image/${type}`,
  };


  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).json({error: 'Upload to s3 failed'});
    }


    // ... more logic 


    return res.json(success : '....');

  });
};
```

I want to export the AWS upload code to a different file and pass it the params without repeating the same code , refactored code :

```
/**
 * Upload image to S3
 */
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const uploadImageToS3 = (params) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });

  // ... handle the upload

  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).json({error: 'Upload to s3 failed'});
    }

    // else handle the data ...

  });
};

export {uploadImageToS3 as default};
```

But how can I use the **callback function** from S3 in any file the will use the refactored code of S3 ?

Answer (score 0):

You must accept the callback as an argument to this function.

As a suggestion, instead of callbacks try using the promise API instead:

```
s3.upload(params).promise().then(data => {}).catch(err => {})
```

You will be able to return a promise from your function and tack on then/catch later.